# How to combine sphinxquerysets in django-sphinx

Tags: django, sphinx, django-sphinx

querysets from django can be combined with a pipe like so:

```
q1 = Articles.objects.filter(name="goats")
q2 = Articles.objects.filter(name='cows')

q1 = q1|q2.
```

Is there a way to do this for sphinxquerysets? So far, I'm striking out.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do something like this in Django? Pass the entire query to Sphinx & let it take care?

Or rather configure your Sphinx setup to search that way. i.e. switch on stemmer, switch on infixor prefix search (depending on your needs) etc.

So what I am trying to say is, one of the main purposes of using a 3rd party search setup is to let it handle the entire search load. So...

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question, and I've either figured out how to do this, or figured some other way around it. I don't remember why I needed to do this though, but thanks for the answer.